# Django subquery using QuerySet

Tags: python, database, django, orm

Is it possible to perform a subquery on a QuerySet using another QuerySet?

For example:

```
q = Something.objects.filter(x=y).extra(where=query_set2)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? The code makes no sense to me. Do you really want to do `query_set2.filter(something__x=y)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No. The [`extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) method doesn't expect *querysets* to be passed in.

If you think about it a bit, it makes sense. Querysets are an abstraction used to represent the results of a fetch operation on the database and `extra` is a convenient way of attaching custom fields from the database to a queryset. Unless you change the fundamental nature of `extra` to mean "custom filtering with another queryset" this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I may understand your question in two ways.

1. You can specify multiple variables
   in your filter parameters, for
   example :

   ```
   q = Something.objects.filter(x=y, w=z)
   ```
2. You want to make what is called a "join" in SQL. This can be done via the aggregation system of Django, see the official [Django Official Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).